# Pip install from private Git repo, with Personal access token in Git URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pip

I am trying to install a package from a private repository on Git.
I am using Personal Access Token in my Git URL in order to bypass the manual authentication step. (You can read about Personal Access Tokens [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line))
If I add this git URL in requirements file and then use the requirements file in pip to install build it works.

```
requirements.txt
<package name> @ git+https://<Personal Access Token>@<git server address>/<username>/<repository name>.git@<branch name>#egg=<package name>
```

But, if I use the same URL directly it asks for password, how do I avoid this password prompt (as mentioned below):

```
pip install git+https://<Personal Access Token>@<git server address>/<username>/<repository name>.git@<branch name>#egg=<package name>
```

This issue is not observed on all machines that i tested on. It worked on Win 10 x64 and Win 10 x86. But it didn't work on Ubuntu x64. I made sure all the 3 systems has same Python version (3.8.0) and same Pip version (19.3.1).

Comment: your second code block, `pip install git+https://...`, worked for installing my personal repo from GitHub in a Colab instance

Answer (score 22):

Use **environment variables** with the syntax `${VARIABLE}` (POSIX format, upper case and underscores allowed) so you're not hard-coding your secrets.

Pip will replace when installing from requirements.txt.

So you can refer to a token to clone the private repo, for example:

in **requirements.txt**

Github

```
git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/user/project.git@{version}
```

Gitlab

```
git+https://${GITLAB_TOKEN_USER}:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/user/project.git@{version}
```

Bitbucket

```
git+https://${BITBUCKET_USER}:${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@bitbucket.org/user/project.git@{version}
```

More info here:
https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html

Comment: I'm using a private github repo, but I can't get your solution to work. I've got an environment variable `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` defined in .bash_profile, and I've got a `requirements.txt` file that contains just one line - `git+https://${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/my_gh_user/my_gh_project.git`. But when I do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I'm prompted to enter a password - specifically, I'm asked: `Password for 'https://github_pat_<remainder of personal access token>@github.com:` . This prompt reads to me as if it's interpreting my PAT as a user. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I got it working after I found a `requirements.txt` I made for another project some time ago. For whatever reason, `pip install -r requirements.txt` works just fine if I specify the requirement like `git+https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/my_gh_user/my_gh_project`, but not if I specify it like `git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/user/project.git@{version}` (your answer). I wish I could remember where I found this format, because every resource I've found seems to agree with your answer and I have no idea why this other format is the only one that works for me.

Comment: Very cool, once again I find myself back at this same question, but now the answer that I gave earlier doesn't work anymore - git now exits with code 128, complaining "Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021", despite the fact that I'm using a token, not a password. *No worries* though, there's another undocumented workaround. Specify `requirements.txt` as `git+https://github.com/my_plaintext_username/my_repo`, then when it asks for username and password, enter ANY text for username, and paste the plain text of your access token as your password, and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue. In the end, I could install the package as follows.

- from the command line:

`pip install mypackagename --no-deps --index-url https://gitlab+deploy-token-mytokenname:tokenpassword@gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/123456789/packages/pypi/simple`

- by specifying it in the `requirements.txt` file:

*(Note that the flask and flask-cors package requirements in the example below are just an example, because it may seem really weird to a reader that the other lines in the example are really content that can be written in a requirements.txt.)*

```
flask==1.1.1
flask-cors==3.0.8
--index-url https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://gitlab+deploy-token-mytokenname:tokenpassword@gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/123456789/packages/pypi/simple
mypackagename
```

Then of course run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Note that both fragments above show how to provide your password, as you asked.

Answer (score 4):

Go to GitLab profile settings and generate an read access token:

[image: GitLab profile]

1. Select access tokens
2. give it a name (you can leave expiration date empty)
3. give it access to read all repositories you have access
4. generate it

Now edit your requirement file:

```
pandas==1.0.5
git+https://yourgitlabuser:<generated_token>@gitlab/group/repo@hash#egg=piplib
requests==2.24.0
```